# Implementing a Simple Search Function in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement a basic search page in the web app I'm developing. Right now the page looks like this

[image]

When a user enters a last name, the controller gets called to search the backend Microsoft SQL Server database for all accounts with that Last name

Right now the HTML form looks like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchAct", "HomeController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <form>
        <div>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="text" id="nameToFind">

            <input type="button" id="submitId" value="submit" />

        </div>
    </form>
}
```

It's supposed to call this controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void SearchAct()
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

which will eventually execute the search and then put the results on the page. However, I can't get the controller to be called. I set a break point on the WriteLine so I know its never getting there and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: The could probably be `FormMethod.Get` rather than Post. You need a parameter in the method to bind to - say `public ActionResult SearchAct(string searchText)` and the input must have a matching `name`  attribute - `name="SearchText"` (but you will find this a lot easier if you use a view model and strongly bind to it using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m = m.SearchText)`. And you method needs to be `ActionResult` and return something. And assuming its `HomeController` and not `HomeControllerController` - then the 2nd paraeter of `BeginForm()` is `"Home"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add name attribute to your text box. Form collection build based on only name  attributes.

Change button type to submit, then it will post your form to controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchAct", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <div>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="nameToFind" name="nameToFind">

        <input type="submit" id="submitId" value="submit" />

    </div>

}

@{
    if(ViewBag.SearchKey != null)
    {
        <span>
            Search Key: @ViewBag.SearchKey
        </span>
    }
}
```

Instead on `Console.WriteLine()` use `ViewBag` to send your required data back to view 
Refer below actions

```
//Get Action for rendering view
public ActionResult SearchAct()
{
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchAct(string nameToFind)
{
    ViewBag.SearchKey = nameToFind;

    return View();
}
```

Action parameter name and text box name attribute value must be same otherwise it will `null`

If your form contains multiple text box then read all input values form `FromCollection` or `Request`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchAct(FormCollection form)
{
    ViewBag.SearchKey = form["nameToFind"];

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

correct your form `HomeController` should be just `Home`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchAct", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <form>
        <div>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="text" id="nameToFind">

            <input type="button" id="submitId" value="submit" />

        </div>
    </form>
}
```

controller should accept the input parameter for your filter

```
[HttpPost]
public void SearchAct(string nameToFind)
{
    // filter snomething
    Console.WriteLine(nameToFind);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First: To create a form via using razor syntax:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchAct", "HomeController", FormMethod.Post))
{

}
```

That would generate a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/HomeController/SearchAct">

</form>
```

So, no need to create a nested form inside that.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchAct", "HomeController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <form> // <- here
        <div>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="text" id="nameToFind">

            <input type="button" id="submitId" value="submit" />

        </div>
    </form> // <- here
}
```

Second: `HomeController` would match the controller what the full name is `HomeControllerController`.

So, if you want to hit `Home` controller, remove `Controller` from `HomeController` in `@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchAct", "HomeController", FormMethod.Post)) {}`

Thirth: if you want to catch `nameToFind`, you can try:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SearchAct(string nameToFind)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

first of all we dont need to two form tag and you dont need to add controller suffix. remve that:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchAct", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
 {
    <div>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="nameToFind" name="nameToFind">

        <input type="button" id="submitId" value="submit" />

    </div>
 }
```

Secondly if you need to search you need to add paramater same as the name of input type text :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SearchAct(string nameToFind)
    {
     Console.WriteLine();
    }
```